# Can't implement getIntent(); method in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I try to implement `getIntent();` in Fragment and display text but I get `Cannot resolve method 'getIntent()'`

Here is part of Fragment3.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_3, container, false);
    TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);
    textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);
```

Here is xml TextView for displaying text

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_display_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

And part of MainActivity regarding this matter

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fragment3.class);

    buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkAnswers())
                intent.putExtra("Key Answer", true);

            else
                intent.putExtra("Key Answer", false);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And here is the whole Fragment3

```
    package make.appaplication;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Fragment41 extends Fragment {


    public Fragment41() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_3, container, false);
        TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);
        textViewDisplayResult.setText(getActivity().getIntent().getB‌​ooleanExtra("KEY_ANS‌​WER", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);

    }


}
```

Comment: change onCreateView method to: 
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_3, container, false);
        TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);
        textViewDisplayResult.setText(getActivity().getIntent().getB‌​ooleanExtra("KEY_ANS‌​WER", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);
return v;
    }

Comment: i.e. make sure operator "return" is called at the end of the method

Comment: still getting `getB‌​ooleanExtra` as `Cannot resolve method 'getB‌​ooleanExtra(java.lang.String, boolean)`. Maybe it's because there is also `"KEY_ANSWER",true` which isn't added to this last line?

Comment: Could you please update your code

Comment: I did it as you suggested Serg and as I said still throwing an error with `getBooleanExtra` :(

Comment: It seems you have some chars inconsistent in your IDE. Try to delete method getBooleanExtra(), place cursor after the dot (after getActivity().getIntent().), use autoComplete (Ctrl+space) and choose that  method from dropDown menu.

Comment: unfortunately no luck, Serg :(

Comment: Strange, it helped me.

Comment: First of all I had this all method in AnswerActivity.java (it worked) and since I moved it to Fragment it has started giving me troubles... I guess something that worked in AnswerActivity.java doesn't apply to Fragments:(

Comment: I'll organize it for tomorrow? Is that ok? First that I don't have skype account and second that I'm using my friend's computer. Would you be able to help me also with how to `wrap around TextView` (have some pictures needed to be wrapped around) and how to add zoom to the app so it will be zoomable - but not zoomable only `TextView` or only `ImageView` but the whole screen?

Comment: I understand. Leave me your e-mail please. I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: The `return` statement needs to be the last line in `onCreateView()`. Furthermore, you don't load a `Fragment` with `startActivity()`, so that's going to crash. You should look into some tutorials for `Fragment`s, or at least read through [the developer page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you Mike. The problem actually was `extends Fragment` whereas it should be `extends AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
getActivity().getIntent();
```

Or you can pass data to fragment directly using arguments:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putBoolean("Key Answer", true);
Fragment f = new YourFragment();
f.setArguments(args);
```

Make sure you set arguments before fragment is added to FragmentManager.

Comment: If I do so, I get `setText` as `Cannot resolve symbol 'setText'`

Comment: Use it like this:     textViewDisplayResult.setText(getActivity().getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);

Comment: I changed for it and now I get `getB‌​ooleanExtra` as `Cannot resolve method 'getB‌​ooleanExtra(java.lang.String, boolean)`

Comment: Serg, what part exactly do you mean? I'm not that good in programming terms yet.

Comment: I guess the code of  Fragment3.java will be enough.

Comment: Updated my post

Answer (score 0):

`getIntent()` is a Activity class method which isn't directly accessible from your fragment. Try calling `getActivity.getIntent()` to get the Activity in context first.

Comment: The same as above - Now I get `setText` as `Cannot resolve symbol 'setText'`