# Can't solve add(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) in List can not be applied to (make.application.Fragment)

Tags: java, android

My Fragment.java

```
    package make.appaplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Fragment41 extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_41);
            TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);

            textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);
        }
    }
```

And in MainActivity

```
fragmentList.add(new Fragment41());
```

throws `add(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) in List can not be applied to (make.application.Fragment)`

I added `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'` and rebuilt but nothing has changed.

Updated code for Lalit user. (I get now three methods `Can not resolve` and underlined `protected`)

```
    package make.appaplication;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragment41 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_41);
        TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);

        textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Fragment41` is an `AppCompatActivity`, not a support `Fragment`, which is what `fragmentList.add()` is expecting. Are you [really sure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416172/cant-implement-getintent-method-in-fragment#comment73910646_43416172) you want `Fragment41` to be an `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Do you even know the difference between `Activity` and `Fragment`?

Comment: Hi Mike, so how can I display in `Fragment41` this TextView?

Comment: @Rotwang, please, don't be so impolite. I know the difference. Forgive me my luck of knowladge on how activity works with fragment.

Comment: At this point, I honestly don't know what you're trying to do, but you had the beginnings of a proper `Fragment` class in [your last post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416172/cant-implement-getintent-method-in-fragment). Fix the `return` statement location, then maybe have a read through the developer page I linked to there to see how to load `Fragment`s in an `Activity`.

Comment: ... impolite? Why do you say so? `I know the difference` it actually seems you do not.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code in

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
}
```

with

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
}
```

and also change import

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: Updated my post. Please have a look Lalit.

Comment: ok but i give my solution this is worked for me i hope u its work for you